# Is it Galois extension?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

If $E/F$ is separable extension,$N/E$ is normal extension,is $N/F$ a galois extenstion?

I guess the answer is no.I do not know how to prove it.If $E_s$ is the separable closure of $F$,$N$ is normal closure of $E_s$,is the $N/F$ is galois extension?

Comment: You can consider the case $E=F$ and $N$ is a normal extension which is not Galois. For instance, the splitting field of $X^p-a$, with $a\in\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ for suitable $a$.

Comment: If $E_s$ is the separable closure of $F$,$N$ is normal closure of $E_s$,is the $N/F$ is galois extension?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not; this can fail in all sorts of different ways.  Basically, there is no reason whatsoever for $N$ to be either normal or separable over $F$, since you are not assuming that $E$ is normal over $F$ or that $N$ is separable over $E$ (in fact, even those assumptions would not be enough to guarantee that $N$ is normal over $F$, but that is more subtle).

For instance, if you take $N=E$, then this would be saying that every separable extension is Galois, which is not true (for instance, consider $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$).  Or if you take $E=F$, this would be saying every normal extension is Galois, which is again false.

Comment: what it will be if $N \ne E $ and $E \ne F $